# In my CustomTabcontrol creates multiple copies of views when binding tabs to an ObservableCollection via datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext

Simply when I bind the ItemsSource of the TabControl to an ObservableCollection of view models, more than one view is created, despite there being only one view model in the ObservableCollection.

This is demonstrated in the project by the fact that the following message is output to the console:
View created ... Id = 1,
View created ... Id = 2
Here is my code

```
MainWindow.XAML
<Grid>
 <custom:TabControlExt   ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"  />
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TestViewModel>();
            Tabs.Add(new TestViewModel());
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<TestViewModel> Tabs { get; set; }
    }
```

TestView.XAML.cs

```
 public partial class TestView : UserControl
    {
        static int __i = 0;
        int _i = 0;

        public TestView()
       {
            __i++;
            _i = __i;
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContextChanged += TestView_DataContextChanged;
            Console.WriteLine("View created ... Id = " + _i);

        }
```

App.XAML

```
<Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestViewModel}">
            <local:TestView />
        </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

Can any one provide solution that why it create two view created

Comment: You'll need to post the code of the TabControlExt class in order to get any reasonable responses to this question. My guess is that the duplicate views are related to how you react to the ItemsSource property changing in the custom control.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have fixed

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderDataTemplate" x:Shared="false"  DataType={x:Type local:TabItemExt}">
    <TextBlock Focusable="False"  Text="{Binding}"  TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" IsHitTestVisible="False" Padding="4,0,4,1" />
   </DataTemplate>


<Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource HeaderDataTemplate}" />
```

but the way i faced some issue when editing HeaderTemplate it will not show header
See below image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPqw0.png)